# Postman Collection Run does pause for setTimeout calls

Tags: collections, postman, settimeout, sleep, pause

I put a simple setTimeout(function(), 10000) call in the Tests section of a request.

Works fine when I run the step by itself.

When I do a Collection Run, the step just gets executed and Postman moves on without pausing.

Is this by design?

I'd rather not have to put a delay of X seconds for *every* step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works as expected , check the console to see when was the request send

make sure request is saved:

[image]

THe orange indication shows that it is unsaved , you have to save it

use the below command in pre-request script.

```
  let moment = require("moment")
  console.log("before:", moment())

  setTimeout(function () { console.log("after:", moment()) }, 10000)
```

and check in console:

[image]

Comment: I can check the console, but I assure you that even without doing that, when I set the timeout to 20 seconds, the step runs in less than one second.  The timeout only has an effect when I run the step by itself, but not in a collection-run.

Comment: @Guy no it sends the request only after 20 second

Comment: make sure you have saved the request

Comment: I found my typo.  Exactly as you said. Thank you!