# How can we add sleep time in postman test?

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I am getting very big response(50k lines). I am getting 200 status and my test code written in Test tab starts getting executed before whole response loaded in postman.

In other words I and to add delay between success response and test starts.

Comment: See if this helps- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477919/how-to-add-a-pause-between-2-requests-in-postman/55471902#55471902

Comment: this is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait until get response by setting the `request timeout` is zero. It means infinity waiting.

unit is milli seconds.

[image]

You can find it from gear the menu of Postman

[image]

You can make timeout error with this URL by 10 msec

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/json-iterator/test-data/master/large-file.json
```

In case of 10 msec,

[image]

[image]

In case of 0 msec,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bench Vue, Thanks for your response but my problem is different.

Comment: OK, no problem. If you more detail information, I will try it with real demo.